# A particular PHP CMS targeted at artists - forgot name

Tags: php, content-management-system

I remember coming across a very minimalistic PHP CMS that targets mainly artists as an easy way to put their portfolio online. It was open source and had an own site. There was a ZIP download, no hosted service as far as I remember.

It was used by a number of artists, including well-known ones. The project site and many implemented sites had vertical menu navigation (i.e. items underneath each other). Now I would like to send the link to a colleague who is planning to re-build his site, but I just can't remember the name anymore. Does any name come to your mind?

Comment: This is soo not a programming question, but upvoted because I'm interested :D

Comment: It's solved already, Indexhibit it was. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.indexhibit.org/